# Prevent Google map marker from being clickable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know if there's a way to prevent a Google map marker from being clickable. I thought this is something that could be set up in the map options using the following code.

```
map_options: {        
    clickable: false,
},
```

I found this in a really old blog post:

http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-make-google-map-marker-non-clickable/

However I'm not sure if this option has been deprecated or not.

Comment: The clickable property on the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a marker from being clickable, set its [clickable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) property to false (won't make much difference if you don't have something to handle the click event, except prevent the cursor from changing).

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    clickable: false
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Script error google side when you click "Run code snippet"

Comment: it is an old question/answer, needed to add the (now required google test) key to the code snippet so the map works